# Is there any way to run unit and ui tests for azure devops with iOS?

Tags: ios, azure

I have researched on app center, for some reason it won't work with our current setup.

I have created a build pipeline for swift codes coming from Xcode. i have my unit and ui tests uploaded as well. I wanted to create a script to trigger test runs in azure devops. Is this possible? I would also want to make sure that running the tests is headless.

Answer (score 6):

Although [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xcode?view=azure-devops) only describes using the [App Center Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/app-center-test?view=azure-devops) in your pipeline, it's also possible to run the tests using the [Xcode task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=azure-devops), by using the `test` action.

Here's an example that runs the tests from MyScheme on the iPad Air simulator and stores the results in JUnit format:

```
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Running tests'
  inputs:
    actions: 'test'
    sdk: 'iphonesimulator'
    configuration: 'Debug'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'MyWorkspace.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'MyScheme'
    xcodeVersion: 'default'
    useXcpretty: true
    publishJUnitResults: true
    args: '-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Air (4th generation)"'
```

You can then publish the results using the [Publish Test Results task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Cyaml):

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publishing test results'
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/junit.xml'
    mergeTestResults: true
    failTaskOnFailedTests: true
```

For a bit of extra background: the docs for the Xcode task say that you should be able to specify the destination by using the `destinationPlatformOption`, `destinationPlatform` and `destinationSimulators` arguments, but I've found they don't escape the result correctly, so I reverted to using the `args` argument to the task shown above.

Anyway I hope that's helpful to someone.

Comment: Is it possible to run the test in real device, by specifying sdk as iphoneos? I got the following error message Cannot test target “TargetName” on “Any iOS Device”: A build only device cannot be used to run this target. No supported iOS devices are available. Connect a device to run your application or choose a simulated device as the destination

Comment: "Cannot test target AbcTests on Any iOS Simulator Device: Tests must be run on a concrete device"- Getting this error on executing the test action of XCode task. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, if you are using native iOS and xCode, AppCenter is the only solution for testing per Microsoft Azure DevOps Docs (see below).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xcode?view=azure-devops

I run tests in AppCenter using XCUITests in an Azure Build Pipeline, so it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact answer to OP question, but hopefully this will at least provide someone with a way forward...

I'm not familiar with your "swift codes coming from Xcode". I just wanted to suggest trying an Appium server on your Mac. I am running tests on an iPad wired to a Mac Mini using TestComplete in tandem with Appium. These are automatically kicked off by an Azure DevOps pipeline and passed to a Windows 11 machine that has the TestExecute client, which then passes tests to the Mac which has an Appium server up. Finally, the Appium server handles running the tests on the physical iPad connected to the Mac. TestComplete/TestExecute requires a license, but Appium is free.

TestComplete has built an adapter for Azure DevOps to interact with TestExecute agents, which in turn handles 'script running' and 'headless' requests. This is the part I'm not clear on, as TestExecute forms this script call for Appium. But this script can technically be formed manually (Appium test snippet for reference).

```
var capabilities = {
    "app": Project.Variables.App,
    "automationName": Project.Variables.AutomationName,
    "bundleID": Project.Variables.Process,
    "deviceName": Project.Variables.DeviceName,
    "platformName": Project.Variables.PlatformName,
    "platformVersion": Project.Variables.PlatformVersion,
    "udid": Project.Variables.Udid
  };
```

My assumption is that Appium would accept a script call directly from DevOps, which requires a bit more research. The TestComplete adapter makes this part a lot easier.

There is some setup involved on the Mac with Appium and its WebDriverAgent (nothing involving Apple has ever been straightforward for me, so good luck).