# Is there anyway to add a iOS UI (XCUI) testing pipeline without using AppCenter?

Tags: ios, azure-devops, continuous-integration, devops, visual-studio-app-center

I am configuring CI/CD pipelines for my project and I have written my UI tests using XCUI framework. I referred Azure documentation for configuring them and I found out to use UI testing we need a AppCenter account.

Is there any way to configure a pipeline without using AppCenter account?

Comment: Hi, I didn't find the documentation that describes another way to run UI test pipeline without AppCenter, we recommend that you create the account and then run the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We didn't find the doc that describes another way to run UI test pipeline without AppCenter, we recommend that you create the account and then run the test.

Then we could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/vsts-plugin) to run the UI test.

Answer (score 0):

I had Xamarin.UITests running on a Mac agent up until around a year ago. These were kicked off directly from an Azure Devops pipeline calling into a Pipeline
Agent on a Mac Mini. People tended to have a lot of issues with App Center and Xcode. Apple automation, on the whole, is a moving target (not to mention the manual, in-person code entry required for "Enable UI Automation"). I kept up with a few issues until I switched to TestComplete.  [Feel free to follow this.](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/2536) [And this.](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/2547)

If App Center is not an option for you, and you're not too invested in your scripts written as they are, I suggest switching to TestComplete which uses Appium's WebDriverAgent as its test runner.
[See a convoluted workaround in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77882146/9457801)

Apple test development is a tricky beast and, as far as I can tell, is made a lot easier by having some license/subscription to something like App Center.